# Example of an ATMF trade in FX market

Tags: fx

Pls give an example of ATMF and how is it different from a regular ATM trade?

Comment: An option is ATM if K=S, an option is ATMF if K=F, where F is the forward price.

Comment: But usually three conventions are widely popular. 1. ATM, 2. ATMS 3. ATMF. When K=S it is ATMS; If K=F, it is ATM, and when ATM is combined with forward hedge it is called ATMF. I am not able to understand how ATMF actually is designed. I am looking for an example. (S= Current Spot, Sources: FX derivative trader school)

Comment: I did not get your point. Can u pls explain it in a bit  more detail pls?

Comment: I think ATMF means a portfolio of 2 trades. Trade1 is ATM trade where strike is forward and Trade2 is a forward hedge to make the portfolio delta neutral. So, if 1 year forward rate for GBPUSD is 110 and Trade1 is 10m long call GBPUSD. Suppose it generates a delta of 0.6 then overall delta position would be 6m USD. So, trade2 would be short 6m USD to make the portfolio delta neutral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of ATM and ATMF in the comments, and my assumption that you are talking about options, an ATM trade would be an option trade where the strike would be spot and the delta would be hedged using the spot market.

An ATMF trade would be an option trade where the strike would be the forward price to the expiry date of the option and the delta would be hedged using the currency forward.

So for example, if you look at EURUSD, Spot = 1.11 and you buy a 3M Call ATMS, the strike would be 1.11.  Hedging the delta in the spot market would be a short 59.84% position the spot EURUSD to be delta neutral.

A 3M Call ATMF would be where the strike would be 1.1173 where spot is 1.11.  Using the Spot to hedge this would be a short position of 49.64% in spot EURUSD to be delta neutral.  Using the forward would be shorting a 49.51% position in the 3M EURUSD forward to be delta neutral.

Comment: When you are saying ATM trade with Strike = spot, it will be true only if we assume that it's a short tenor trade.